# FluentNHibernate dll's, what to install when I have NH3.0?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have installed latest dlls of **NHibernate 3.0** (and Castle). I now want to install **Fluent-1.1**. The Fluent download also includes standard NHibernate and Castle dlls, but I would guess not latest versions. So do I need to roll back in some way, or can I just install ***some*** of the dlls in FluentNHibrenate 1.1  ?

If I can pick selected dlls from fluent and add, would that be: 
**FluentNHibernate** and **log4net**? What about **Castle.DynamicProxy2**? Why is that part of Fluent, but not part of the NH3.0 download?

http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/1919/ss20110126234232.png
[image: http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/1919/ss20110126234232.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download and use the NHibernate 3 binaries available from the Fluent NHibernate [downloads page](http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads) (under "Stable pre-release binaries").

Comment: Indeed. I don't know how I managed, but I mistakenly did not fetch the last Fluent version..  uh.. :)

Comment: download page is now a broken link

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to both, but I would guess, based on some of the docs on the Fluent Wiki, that you would need to get the source code for both products, or at least Fluent, and then recompile Fluent referencing the NHibernate 3.0 DLLs (or project).

Comment: Ok I'm just a newbie, but this sounds unlikely to me (?)  Their download page have 3 main options: Binary for NH3.0, for NH2.1.2, and Source (http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads). The two binaries include NHibernate dlls, so to me that looks like fully "matched" set of both Fluent and NH. ?

Comment: Maybe I should just put them side by side in my sharedLibs, and use the versions provided in the Fluent download for my Fluent projects..

Comment: The different binaries are for the 1.x pre-release version that will become Fluent 1.2.  It's not Fluent 1.1.  My understanding is that Fluent 1.1 was built with NH2.1.2.  And so it's those DLLs that are included with it.  I don't think it would work to just drop in the NH3.0 DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) to get the synchronized versions of all your dlls.